# Get Users from Active Directory running on Windows Server in Azure Cloud

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, windows-server

I'd like to read out all users on an active directory running on a windows server 2016 inside a azure cloud. I can access the windows server with remote desktop but I'm not able to use the PrincipalContext of the DirectoryServices to connect to the AD. I have the IP-Address of the remote windows server 2016 on which the active directory service is running. A user with admin rights was also created.

I tried different statements regarding the connection of the PrincipalContext.

1.

```cs
using (var adContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "ip-adress of remote server"))
```

2. 

```cs
using (var adContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "LDAP://ip-adress of remote server"))
```

3. 

```cs
 using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "ip-adress of remote server", "CN=Users", "adminuser", "adminpassword")
```

The exception I'm getting is System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalServerDownException: 'The server could not be contacted. Is there an issue because the server is not in the same domain?

This is my first time doing anything regarding active directory or windows server. So if there is some giant error in in my approach please be considerate.

Comment: Can you instead check with "server-hostname" or "domain-name", instead of ip-address? You can get that information with server administration team in your organisation.

Comment: Is the server hostname the full computername of the server? If so the result is the same.

Comment: Hi @madibat. As you mentioned that *Is there an issue because the server is not in the same domain?*, I suspect that the port 389/636 is not available for default bind from your source system! Can you please verify the same if you're able to do telnet or a socket connection test to *-ip-adress of remote server-* on port 389/636?

Comment: Hi @Am_I_Helpful. I Tested it with the Test-NetConnection for both Port 389/636 and both are availble.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a firewall issue - you just can't contact the server over the network. You can test this in PowerShell using the command:

```
Test-NetConnection "ip-adress of remote server" -Port 389
```

There are 4 ports you can test:

- 389: The default LDAP port. This is used if you don't specify a port.
- 636: LDAPS, or LDAP over SSL (encrypted)
- 3268: Global Catalog. Works the same as LDAP, but includes all domains in your forest (if you have more than one domain)
- 3269: GC over SSL

If any of the other ports work, then you can specify it in the `PrincipalContext`:

```
new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "ip-adress of remote server:636")
```

Using SSL complicates things a little since your computer needs to trust the SSL certificate that the server sends.

If none of the ports work, then there is a firewall blocking communication somewhere and you need to get that fixed first.

Comment: Port 389 and 636 can be reached via Test-NetConnection and the ipadress, but I still get the same error when its used in the PrincipalContext

Comment: Can you browse your Active Directory on the server itself? (if you open Active Directory Users and Computers, for example)

Comment: Yes, thats no issue. I have a adminuser for the server and can browse everything. I also created some users in the AD.

Comment: Gabriel, did you mean to install aduc on the client where the code is running?

Comment: @oldovets No, I was talking about the server. If `Test-NetConnection` works, then that means *something* is listening on port 389. If ADUC works on the server, then that should mean AD is listening on port 389. If it doesn't work outside of the server, then something else must be interfering in the communication.

Comment: Ok, I see. Always used telnet before, lol. What I do here as a last resort in such situation is installing MS tools on the client computer such as aduc or ldp.exe. If the tool successfully connects, there’s a code problem, otherwise - network configuration issue

Comment: @oldovets Yeah, I use telnet too usually. But the telnet client is not installed by default in Windows 10 anymore, but PowerShell always is. So that's why I suggest testing with PowerShell instead of telnet.

Comment: But yes, installing ADUC or [LDP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc772839(v=ws.10)) on the client machine would probably be a good next step here.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Yeah, had to install telnet every time. You showed me that this is not the only option. I’ve learned something today. Thanks